# How to add CSS Hack which work for IE 10 & 11

Tags: css, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11

apologized that i am not css guy but still looking for small favor. please see my below css

where i specify `margin top 60px` for all browser and also specified the same like -60px for different IE version. i want to apply the same for IE10 & 11 but i have limited knowledge to `css`. so anyone please help what i need to add to `.arrange_collection_today` which works for IE10 and 11. please guide. thanks

```
.arrange_collection_today
{
    margin-top: 60px;

    _margin-top:-60px; /* Only works in IE6 */
    *margin-top:-60px; /* IE6, IE7 */
    +margin-top:-60px;/* Only works in IE7*/
    *+margin-top:-60px; /* Only works in IE7 */
    margin-top:-60px\9; /* IE6, IE7, IE8, IE9 */
    margin-top:-60px\0; /* IE8, IE9 */
    margin-top:-60px\9\0;/*Only works in IE9*/                        
}
```

Comment: Why are you using, or *wanting* to use, CSS hacks for IE 10+? What makes you think you need to?

Comment: yes @David what is your problem. i faced css problem for IE 11 and that is why i asked a question here. the way u put ur statement that seems very rude.

Comment: Internet Explorer 10, and 11, are pretty good browsers, there are some missing features, of course, just as with Chrome, Firefox etc. You *shouldn't need to* use CSS hacks to target them, as long as you're using valid CSS. Though there's always edge-cases, I suppose. If you feel I'm being rude, feel free to flag my comment (as 'offensive' presumably), or raise the issue by asking a question over on [Meta] for support/help/guidance.

Comment: @david: i am here to get some solution rather do not like to spend time to launch any complain against anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Updated the classes for IE10 and IE 11

```
.arrange_collection_today
{
    _margin-top:-60px; /* Only works in IE6 */
    *margin-top:-60px; /* IE6, IE7 */
    +margin-top:-60px;/* Only works in IE7*/
    *+margin-top:-60px; /* Only works in IE7 */
    margin-top:-60px\9; /* IE6, IE7, IE8, IE9 */
    margin-top:-60px\0; /* IE8, IE9 */
    margin-top:-60px\9\0;/*Only works in IE9*/                        
}

. ie10 .arrange_collection_today { margin-top:-60px; } /* Only works in IE10 */ 

*::-ms-backdrop, .arrange_collection_today { margin-top:-60px } /* IE11 */
```

Comment: please edit my css and put necessary element as a result my arrange_collection_today class should work for IE10 & 11. thanks

Comment: what is the meaning of this *::-ms-backdrop ? please guide. thanks

Comment: is there any tool or online tool which simulate web page for IE 10 or 11....but free to access.

Answer (score 1):

I have stepped away from CSS hacks, as they are hard to maintain and may result in unexpected behavior in other/future browsers. Instead, I'm using a JavaScript solution that adds a class name to the HTML element.

```
(function() {
    var ua = navigator.userAgent;

    function addClass(className) {
        // jQuery:
        $('html').addClass(className);
        // Or plain JS:
        // document.documentElement.className += ' ' + className;
    }

    // This block is the part you want.
    // I don't add versions for gecko or webkit because they release a new version very often.
    if ((/msie/gi).test(ua)) { addClass('ie' + document.documentMode); }
    if ((/gecko\//gi).test(ua)) { addClass('gecko'); }
    if ((/webkit/gi).test(ua)) { addClass('webkit'); }

    // Platform.
    if ((/macintosh/gi).test(ua)) { addClass('mac'); }
    if ((/windows/gi).test(ua)) { addClass('win'); }
    if ((/linux/gi).test(ua)) { addClass('lin'); }

    // Detect browsers with touch capabilities.
    // I'm using it to show or hide instructions.
    if ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) {
        addClass('touch-enabled');
    }
})();
```

I can then do this:

```
.ie9 .arrange_collection_today {
    color: blue;
}

.ie10 .arrange_collection_today {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: is there any tool or online tool which simulate web page for IE 10 or 11....but free to access.

Comment: Microsoft provides a multiple free tools/services to test Internet Explorer: https://remote.modern.ie and https://www.modern.ie/en-gb/virtualization-tools